# error when calculating the final result in the second person using array

Tags: c

after get the average of assignment and quiz, the program count the value of average.Average*0.20 for assignment and average*0.10 for quiz.The results of calculations for the first person are correct, but when it comes to the second person,the results produced are not in accordance with the calculations.

the code:

```
struct student{
  char id[10];
  char fname[25];
  char lname[25];
  char letter[10];
  int quiz[3];
  int assignment[3];
  int project;
  int MID;
  int Final;
  int grade;
  int percentage;
  int average;
  int sum;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct student person[10];
  int input,count=0,count2=0,choose;

  printf("Input Student : ");
  scanf("%d",&input );
  printf("\n");

  int i,j,k;
  for ( i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    printf("Input Id : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].id);
    printf("Input Name : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].fname);
    scanf("%s",person[i].lname);
    printf("\n");

    //input assignment
    for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("Input Assignment%d : ",j );
      scanf("%d",&person[j].assignment[i] );
      count+=person[j].assignment[i];
      person[i].average = count/3;
    }
    person[i].percentage = person[i].average*0.20;

    printf("\n");
    //input quiz
    for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      printf("Input Quiz%d : ",k );
      scanf("%d",&person[k].quiz[i] );
      count2+=person[k].quiz[i];
      person[i].average = count2/4;
    }
    person[i].sum = person[i].average*0.10;
    printf("\n");

    //input Project
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].project );
    person[i].project= person[i].project * 0.15;
    printf("\n");

    //input MID
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].MID );
    person[i].MID= person[i].MID * 0.25;
    printf("\n");

    //input Final
    printf("Input Project Value%d : ",i );
    scanf("%d",&person[i].Final );
    person[i].Final= person[i].Final * 0.25;

    //count Grade
    person[i].grade = person[i].percentage + person[i].sum + person[i].project + person[i].MID + person[i].Final;

    printf("\n");
  }

switch (choose) {
    case 1:
      printf("+--------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
      printf("|%8s|%16s|%20s|%25s|%10s|%10s|%10s|%10s|%10s|\n", "NIM", "Name", "Assignment 20%","Quiz 10%","Project 15%","MID 25%","Final 25%","Grade","Huruf");
      printf("|\t |\t\t  |%4s|%4s|%4s|%5s|","I","II","III","20%");
      printf("%4s|%4s|%4s|%4s|%5s|","I","II","III","IV","10%");
      printf("%11s|%10s|%10s|","15%","25%","25%" );
      printf("%10s|%10s|\n"," "," ");
      printf("+--------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
      for ( i = 0; i < input; i++) {
        printf("|%8s|%8s %-7s|", person[i].id,person[i].fname, person[i].lname );

        // count assignment
        for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          printf("%4d|",person[j].assignment[i]);
        }
        printf("%5d|",person[i].percentage);

        // count the quiz
        for ( k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
          printf("%4d|",person[k].quiz[i]);
        }
        printf("%5d|",person[i].sum);

        //print the Project
        printf("%11d|",person[i].project );
        //print the MID
        printf("%10d|",person[i].MID );
        //print the Final
        printf("%10d|",person[i].Final );
        //print Grade
        if (person[i].grade <=100) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"A" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >84) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"A-" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >81) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"B+" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >77) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"B" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >74) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"B-" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >69) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"C+" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >66) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"C" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >59) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"C-" );
        }
        else if (person[i].grade >39) {
          printf("%10d|%10s|\n",person[i].grade,"D" );

        }
      }
      printf("+--------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    break;

    case 2:
      printf("%5s %14s\n","Final Value","Grade" );
      printf("=============%6s=========\n"," ");
      printf("%5s %17s\n","91-100","A" );
      printf("%5s %19s\n","85-90","A-" );
      printf("%5s %19s\n","82-84","B+" );
      printf("%5s %18s\n","78-81","B" );
      printf("%5s %19s\n","75-77","B-" );
      printf("%5s %19s\n","70-74","C+" );
      printf("%5s %18s\n","67-69","C" );
      printf("%5s %19s\n","60-66","C-" );
      printf("%5s %18s\n","40-59","D" );
    break;
    default:
    printf("error");
    return 0;
}
```

expected output :
if i input 60 three times for assignment and 60 four times for quiz, and  count each average then the result of each average multiply with 0.20 for assignment and 0.10 for quiz.

here's the source code : https://github.com/PrinceSP/compro-1/blob/master/compro2/Structure/Exercise2.c

Comment: `printf("%4d|",person[j].assignment[i]);` is wrong.

Comment: Also `printf("%4d|",person[k].quiz[i]);` is wrong.

Comment: Also `scanf("%d",&person[k].quiz[i] );` - it looks like you are confused about how indices work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is when you start the first for loop ,you don't set the count and count2 to zero so when you type the information the second time count and count2 have values from the first time.
so your code in main function should be something like this

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct student person[10];
  int input,count=0,count2=0,choose;

  printf("Input Student : ");
  scanf("%d",&input );
  printf("\n");

  int i,j,k;
  for ( i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    count=0;
    count2=0;
    printf("Input Id : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].id);
    printf("Input Name : ");
    scanf("%s",person[i].fname);
    ....
```

Comment: i forget about that. Your answer is so helpful and the code works. Thanks!